# Exception in thread Null PointerException

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

I am implementing SortedLinkedSet using sortedLinkedSetNode,but i am getting null pointer exception when I am calling SortedLinkedSet using test class please help me.
SortedLinkedSet.java

```
public class SortedLinkedSet implements Set {
protected SortedLinkedSetNode firstNode;

public SortedLinkedSet(SortedLinkedSetNode n) { firstNode = n ; }
public SortedLinkedSet() { firstNode = null; }

// Basic operations
public int size() {
    if (firstNode == null) return 0;
    else return firstNode.size();
}

public String min() throws SortedLinkedSetException {
    if (firstNode == null) throw new SortedLinkedSetException("Empty");
    else return firstNode.min();
}
public String max() throws SortedLinkedSetException {
    if (firstNode == null) throw new SortedLinkedSetException("Empty");
    else return firstNode.max();
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return ( firstNode == null ? true : false );
}
public boolean contains(String el) {
    if (firstNode == null) { return false; }
    else return firstNode.contains(el);
}
public boolean add(String el) {
    System.out.print("add " + el + "\n");
    if (firstNode == null || firstNode.getValue().compareTo(el) < 0 ) {
        //the new element will become the new first node
        firstNode = new SortedLinkedSetNode(el,firstNode);
        return true;
    } else { 
        return firstNode.add(el); //here i am getting 3rd error
    }
}
public boolean remove(String el) { 
    if (firstNode == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (firstNode.getValue().equals(el)) { 
        firstNode = firstNode.getNext();
        return true;
    } else {
        return firstNode.remove(el); 
    }
}


@Override public String toString() {
    if(firstNode == null) {
        return "[]";
    } else {
        return "[" + firstNode.toString() + "]";
    }
}

// Output operations
public void PrettyPrint() {
    System.out.printf(this.toString() + "\n");
}

}
```

SortedLinkedSetNode.java

```
import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.NextAction;
import java.lang.*;

public class SortedLinkedSetNode implements Set {
protected String value;
protected SortedLinkedSetNode next;

public SortedLinkedSetNode(String v, SortedLinkedSetNode n) {
this.value=v;
    this.next=n;
}
public SortedLinkedSetNode(String v) {
this.value=v;
    this.next=null;
}
public SortedLinkedSetNode()
{

}
public String getValue() {
    return this.value;
}

public SortedLinkedSetNode getNext() {
    return this.next;
}
static String s="";

// Basic operations
public int size() {
    if (this == null) return 0;
    else return this.next.size()+1;

}

public String min() throws SortedLinkedSetException {
           if(this.next==null) return this.value;
   else{
       String m=this.next.min();
       if(m.compareTo(this.value)<0)
           return m;
       else
           return this.value;

   }
}

public String max() {


   if(this.next==null) return this.value;
   else{
       String m=this.next.max();
       if(m.compareTo(this.value)>0)
           return m;
       else
           return this.value;

   }
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return ( this == null ? true : false );
}

public boolean contains(String el) {
   if(this==null) return false;
   else
       if(this.value.equalsIgnoreCase(el)) return true;
       else return this.next.contains(el);

}

public boolean add(String el) {

  if(this==null ) 
  {
       this.next=new SortedLinkedSetNode();
      SortedLinkedSetNode n=this;
      this.value = el;
      this.next=n;
      return true;
  }
  if(this.getValue().compareTo(el)<0)  //  here i am getting 1st error
  {
      SortedLinkedSetNode n=this;
      this.value = el;
      this.next=n;
      return true;
  }
  else
  {
      if(this.next==null)
      {
          this.next=new SortedLinkedSetNode();
      }
      return this.next.add(el);    //here i am getting error
  }
}

public boolean remove(String element) {
   if(this==null) return false;
   else
   {

       if(this.value.equalsIgnoreCase(element)) 
       {
           this.value=this.next.value;
           this.next=this.next.next;
           return true;
       }
       else
          return this.next.remove(element);
   }
}

public String toString() {
    if(this==null)
    {
        return s.concat(" ");
    }
    else
    {

        s.concat(" ");
        s.concat(this.value);
        if(this.next!=null)
        {
          s.concat(" ;");  
        }
        return this.getNext().toString();
    }
}

public void PrettyPrint() {
System.out.printf(this.toString() + "\n");
}
}
```

Exception trace:

```
Test t1: {} PASS. Test t2: {add b add a in if Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException in if 
at SortedLinkedSetNode.add(SortedLinkedSetNode.java:99) 
at SortedLinkedSetNode.add(SortedLinkedSetNode.java:112) 
at SortedLinkedSet.add(SortedLinkedSet.java:51) 
at Test2.test(Test2.java:20) 
at TestHarness.run(TestHarness.java:43) 
at Test.main(Test.java:25) Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Could you post a stack trace?

Comment: And what line throws this exception?

Comment: Test t1: {} PASS.
Test t2: {add b
add a
in if
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
in if
 at SortedLinkedSetNode.add(SortedLinkedSetNode.java:99)
 at SortedLinkedSetNode.add(SortedLinkedSetNode.java:112)
 at SortedLinkedSet.add(SortedLinkedSet.java:51)
 at Test2.test(Test2.java:20)
 at TestHarness.run(TestHarness.java:43)
 at Test.main(Test.java:25)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Rather than posting ALL of your code, narrow it down to only the relevant section. Put a comment by the line where the exception is thrown. Give us some information about what the debugger says those variables are holding (i.e. show some debugging effort). DO NOT POST STACK TRACES IN THE COMMENTS!

Comment: I have commented the line where i am getting error

Comment: So what have you done to debug it????  (Null pointer exception is one of the easiest problems to debug.  You should show that you've exhausted all reasonable debugging avenues before posting here.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because user has not exhibited an effort to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
new SortedLinkedSetNode().getValue().compareTo("some string");
```

This is essentially what's happening when you call `SortedLinkedSetNode.add` when you reach the `else` block and `next` is `null`. However, your default constructor leaves the node's value as `null`, so the above resolves to `null.compareTo("some string")`.

You should either set `value` to something non-null (such as the empty string) in your default constructor, or check that the return value of `getValue` is non-null before performing operations on it.

---

As a side note, `if (this == null)` will always evaluate to `false`. The program is not going to enter the method of a null object (it will throw a `NullPointerException` instead). You have several methods whose logic depends on this comparison, which **will** break, either logically (`isEmpty` will always return `false`, for example) or functionally. In several cases, `if (this == null)` is your termination condition for a recursive method, meaning you're going to hit more `NullPointerExceptions` once you get this one figured out.

Try using `if (this.next == null)` as a termination condition for your recursive methods instead. For `isEmpty`, try using something such as `return this.value == null && (this.next == null || this.next.isEmpty())`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this == null)
```

you can't have this.next, this.value etc.  Make sure the object exists and all its subfields have been initialized, before you refer to them.

Comment: if `this` is `null`, the program execution will never even make it into the method. That entire block will never be executed.

Comment: How should i make sure that object exists and all its subfields have been initialized

Comment: initialize all the subfields as needed.